# Using unnecessary hexadecimal notation?

Tags: c++, macros, hex

Whilst reading [Apple's dlfcn.h header](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-360.19/include/dlfcn.h.auto.html) I can across these macros:

```
    #define RTLD_LAZY   0x1
    #define RTLD_NOW    0x2
    #define RTLD_LOCAL  0x4
    #define RTLD_GLOBAL 0x8
```

Is there any reason why the author of this header wrote these as hexadecimal numbers when the prefixing `0x` could be removed safely? `0x1`, `0x2` etc are the same numbers as without `0x`.

Is this just personal coding style?

Comment: Suppose you wanted to add a fifth value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's conventional to use hexadecimal rather than decimal for powers-of-2 sequences, because it scales legibly.

Sure, there are only four options here, but consider a possible extension:

```
0x01
0x02
0x04
0x08
0x10
0x20
0x40
0x80
// ...
```

While the equivalent sequence rendered in decimal notation will be instantly familiar to any programmer, it's not as legible/symmetrical:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
// ...
```

So, using hexadecimal here becomes a convention.

Besides that, sure, style. Some people like to use hex for "numbers used by the computer" because it looks kind of robotic; c.f. decimal for "numbers used by humans".

Consider also that values using use of these constants are likely to be manipulated using bitwise operators (which are similarly convenient to do in hex), and viewed in debuggers that give byte values in hexadecimal. It's easier to cross-reference the values in source code if they use the same base as the program's operations and your tools. 0x22 is easier to understand in this context than 34 is.

Ultimately, you may as well ask why we *ever* use hexadecimal instead of decimal, since there is always a valid conversion between the two. The truth is that some bases are just more convenient than others in certain scenarios. You wouldn't count on your fingers in binary, because you have ten of them.

Comment: Thanks for editing to add the equivalent series in decimal. All makes sense now :)